# Make tumblr photo captions into separate text post?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering - I have a theme on my tumblog where photos stick to the background while text posts can scroll. It can be found [here](http://kibstar.co.vu), if my description is confusing. I was wondering how to make it so that on the theme, the caption appears as a separate text post - if captions are turned on currently, they look like this:

[image]

To fix this, right now I am posting separate text posts to caption each photo. I've changed the post block from this

```
{block:Caption}
     <div class="text post-bg">
   <div class="text-block"><span>{Caption}</span></div>{/block:Caption}
```

to this

```
{block:Caption}
     <div class="text post-bg">
   <div class="text-block"><span>{Caption}</span></div>{/block:Caption}
</div>
```

but this just makes a transparent description in the style of a text post appear above the photo.
Is it possible to change it so that this description appears as a separate post, below the photo post, without actually going in and making text posts for each one?
Thank you for your help! I appreciate it!

Comment: I would add a link to so an example of the `transparent description in the style of a text post appear above the photo`.

Comment: @mikedidthis I appreciate your suggestion, and I would have done so, but I don't have enough reputation to put three links in a post yet. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware of the restriction. You should have a link free now.